# Add a variable to store a user’s first name using console.readLine

Tags: store, console.readline

I am new to Java, and I would like to know the answer for this question. 
Why isn't the first line enough to store that value? Thanks.

printscreen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CjkI.png

Comment: If you have just one line of code just paste it here please.

Comment: string firstName = console.readLine("What is your name?");